# How to make TriggerEnter working in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers

i'm trying to make character to lose hp when it hits enemy trigger, but it's not working I'm using OnTriggerEnter2D and debugging triggers name, but there's nothing in logs.

[Enemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJin1.png)

[Character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3XMV.png)

[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy4ms.png)

Comment: Please share the script , not as an image, to make debugging possible for people trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they on the same layer? Try debugging if they collide at all and make sure the colliders trigger flag is true. Try also to put on both objects Rigidbody2D and see if it helps.